# Replace one component with another using animation

Tags: animation, react-native

I'm looking to animate a text field into view and a button out of view at the same time, so that it looks like the text field is replacing the button. (They are both equal size and take up the same area of the screen).

What's the best way to do this using React Native animation?

At this point, I am rendering the button if one of my state values is false, and the text field if it is true.

Answer (score 2):

You can animate any style property in react-native using the Animated API.
If you are able to represent the changes in a sequence of style changes, the Animated API can do it. For instance animating the opacity from 1 to 0 and back to 1 will give a nice fade in fade out effect. The docs explain the Animations much more clearly

Also you can you selective rendering to mount or hide the component

```
<View style={{/*style props that need to be animated*/}}
{ boolShowText? <Text/> : <View/> }
</View>
```

The fading example as found in react-native docs

```
class FadeInView extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0), // init opacity 0
   };
}
componentDidMount() {
  Animated.timing(          // Uses easing functions
    this.state.fadeAnim,    // The value to drive
    {toValue: 1},           // Configuration
  ).start();                // Don't forget start!
}
render() {
  return (
    <Animated.View          // Special animatable View
      style={{opacity: this.state.fadeAnim}}> // Binds
      {this.props.children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: So @nishanth, using your example above, how would you animate the text fading away while the child view fades in?

Comment: as mentioned in the text you can animate the opacity state from 1 to 0 to and 1 sequentially. You can also get callbacks after each animation to swap the components